# Parsing CUDA code with clang

Tags: cuda, clang, llvm

I am new to Clang. Is it possible to parse CUDA code with clang and emit LLVM IR? I don't find any proper support for this on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Cuda has a llvm compiler: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-llvm-compiler

If you just want a llvm compiler, you can use it.

If you just want use the clang to parse cuda code, I think it couldn't do it.